# Method types within a Class in VB.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

A friend asked me this and not sure how to understand.  Prolly a simple answer.

He has the following

`Public Class TestClass
     Public Sub Setup()
        MsgBox ("Hello")
     End Sub
  End Class`

Based on that example, what type of member is Setup, in relation to the TestClass class?

I think it it might be an instance member.  Because a class is just a collection of instances (methods, properties, etc) within the class.

Correct?

Comment: Correct. it is an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an *instance method* as opposed to a *class method* (`static` methods).

> When a field, method, property, event, indexer, constructor, or destructor declaration does not include a static modifier, it declares an instance member.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Initially my answer said that a member is the same as a field. According to the MSDN link above this was not entirely correct so I adjusted it. You'll also notice that they use the term *static member* instead of *instance member*.

Terminology is a very tricky subject and you'll notice people use many different descriptions for the same subject. This is further amplified when you take other languages in consideration and the terminology there.

Answer (score 0):

It is an instance method, but **not because a class is a collection of instances**.

It is an instance method because TestClass is not shared (static), and must be **instantiated**. That is, there must be a instance of TestClass available to use its method Setup(). Conversely, with a Shared class, you do not need an instance of TestClass to use Setup(), it would be a Shared method and not an instance method.

That is academic, however, since VB does not support static classes (Shared Classes), but does support shared methods, the effective difference is that declaring Setup() as Public makes it an instance method, or declaring it as Shared would make it a static method.

Comment: Thanx, that makes sense.  And, was a bit unaware of the VB handling